# Magento 2 - Admin Product Page - Rearrange tabs that are not in the attribute set

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel

I've been searching for quite a while without any luck... I want to know how to rearrange the tabs on the **admin product page**, only those that **can't be modified from the attribute set** drag and drop option.

Specifically, I want to move "**Product in Websites**" to the top:

[image: What I want to do]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution is in this file:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Websites.php**

On line 140, you'll need to change "search-engine-optimization" to "product-details" in my case. That'll move the tab to the top.

Of course you'll want to override this file by creating a plugin, not changing the core file.